# php define and after use unset vars (not working)

Tags: php

I'm having memory problems with my server (server down right now) so I need to find a way of free memory after use.

My app uses mysql records witch i use as defined variables.

I was guessing I could fill in a array, use values when needed and at the end unset all, but my test doesn't work...

here is my example code, hope you can help, thanks

[image: teste]

Comment: you know you can copy/paste the code here?

Comment: It's simpler to just unset the whole array `unset($array_defs);`. Its occupied memory will be reused later. The `define()`d constants will never be freed however.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use constants here anyways!

Answer (score 1):

If your server is down the problem can't be a PHP script because there is a memory_limit setting for php script.

Also after the exit of your script every memory allocated is freed automatically

Comment: thanks for reply, my host company says the problem are opened sessions, but I'm not using sessions. this start happening when I started with this app, witch makes intensive use of php defined variables. I assumed it was something related to that. Mayby a stupid question, but using define consumes server or browser memory? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're defining named constants which you then try to store in an array. Why? And what does this have to do with mysql?

What you are calling 'define' variables doesn't define any variables, it creates constants. Read about define and named constants in the PHP manual.

It doesn't make any sense at all to try defining constants with query results.

In PHP you rarely have to thing about memory yourself at all since after every roundtrip the allocated memory of a script will be freed. So your problem is somewhere else. Might be that your memory limit, script execution time or other configuration parameters are not set correctly in the context of your app.

Comment: hello, the array was just to unset all at the end. this is just a test, in real app i use $row = mysql_fetch_assoc and then foreach ($row as $i => $definicao) define($i, $definicao)

Comment: that's what I'm saying, you should NOT use constants, why are doing that?

Comment: because I need to use values in different functions, I was defining one time and then reusing each time I need it. I Realize now that it was a big mistake.

Comment: You need no constants for that, you just pass the result or parts of it around into your functions.